# SELECT where ID matches one of a list

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, expressionengine, expresso-store

I'm just learning the ins and outs of MYSQL queries but I've run into a roadblock with a project and I'd appreciate some help reaching a solution.

I have two tables, the first contains a reference to the entry (entry_id) and the modification associated (mod_id) as well as the category of modification it refers to (mod_name)

Table 1: exp_store_product_options

```
mod_id      entry_id        mod_name
3           2919            COLOR
4           2311            SIZE
5           2311            COLOR
6           3301            COLOR
```

the second table contains two relevant fields, mod_id and opt_name

Table 2: exp_store_product_modifiers

```
mod_id      opt_name
3           BLACK
4           EU 44
5           BROWN
6           BROWN
```

What I am trying to achieve, is a listing of all the DISTINCT opt_name fields that (through a join on the mod_id) correspond to entry_ids that I would like to pass in as a lump.

here is the code I've come up with so far, I believe it'll do what I need aside from requiring me to loop through the query for each entry id, and failing on the DISTINCT requirement since for each iteration, everything is distinct. (the {sale_products} tags are from ExpressionEngine, and will loop during the parse to provide me with a list of the entry_id results that are relevant to this page

```
SELECT DISTINCT opt_name
FROM exp_store_product_options
INNER JOIN exp_store_product_modifiers
ON exp_store_product_options.product_mod_id=exp_store_product_modifiers.product_mod_id
{sale_products parse='inward'}entry_id = '{entry_id}' OR{/sale_products}
AND mod_name = 'SIZE'
```

====================================================

## POSTMORTEM

Just in case anyone else is trying to work within expresso's Store module for ExpressionEngine and needs to build some rudimentary filtering into your templates, here's the code I ultimately got to work. Very similar to Ben's code, but utilizing embeds instead of directly inserting the entry_ids because of issues with parse order:

the template: embeds/product_filter

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT DISTINCT opt_name
FROM exp_store_product_modifiers
LEFT JOIN exp_store_product_options
ON exp_store_product_options.product_mod_id = exp_store_product_modifiers.product_mod_id
WHERE exp_store_product_modifiers.entry_id IN ({embed:entry_ids})
AND exp_store_product_modifiers.mod_name = '{embed:filter_on}'"
}

<li><a href="#">{opt_name}</a></li>
{/exp:query}
```

with an {embed} that looks like

```
{embed="embeds/product_filter" entry_ids="{sale_products backspace='1'}{entry_id},{/sale_products}" filter_on="SIZE"}
```

Comment: So what''s your question? It seems like you found the solution already?

Comment: Ben, my question is how do I get a list of unique opt_names from a list of associated entries. Basically the english version of what I want is, for this list of entry ids, find all the associated opt_names and return just one instance of each. If that helps...

Comment: -evanr, use 'IN'. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a list of entries, you can use `IN`. Also, I'd use a `LEFT JOIN` here instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT opt_name
FROM exp_store_product_options
LEFT JOIN exp_store_product_modifiers
  ON exp_store_product_options.product_mod_id = exp_store_product_modifiers.product_mod_id
WHERE exp_store_product_options.entry_id IN (1,2,3)
AND mod_name = 'SIZE'
```

Comment: and the 1,2,3 would correspond to the entry_ids column in the first table?

Comment: @evanr, yes, those are the entry_ids.